# How to determine if it is day or night in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

Im wanting to apply different CSS sheets to my site depending on the time of the browser. e.g if its day time, display day.css or night.css for night.

I can do this with PHP but it is based on the server time, not the browsers local time.

Is there a way to tell the time in javascript? I'm probably going to use jQuery to simply initiate the css once its worked out.

Comment: You don't need to javascript for this task. Just go upstairs and open the curtains.

Comment: You can still do it in PHP based on the clients local-time.... but you'll have to use some sort of IP to Location service, which isn't completely reliable.

Comment: This is a great question and a possibly great feature, but there's a possibiliity that this could go haywire. I've used computers before that have times set incorrectly (like the hour being way off). One such comp was with Vista: after sychronizing it with Internet clocks, it reverted. So, there may be cases where you might inaccurately interpret the data. Well, there may be cases where the data is incorrect. If this is more about theme and you don't really care if it's incorrect in some cases, certainly go ahead, but otherwise, you might not want this. I don't know what I'd do. Good luck!

Comment: lol @Mark :)

thanks @Maxim. very good things to consider. i think considering php acts on the server time, and we get visitors all around the world i think the theme would show the correct day or night more often than not.

its really just a novelty add on. cheers!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
var hr = (new Date()).getHours(); //get hours of the day in 24Hr format (0-23)
```

Depending on your definition of day/night, perform your magic :)

PS: If your day/night starts not at the exact hour, you can try `getMinutes()`.

Answer (score 13):

I use this logic:

```
const hours = new Date().getHours()
const isDayTime = hours > 6 && hours < 20
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(new Date).getHours()
```

will get the local hour of the time (0-23) of the client. Based on that value, swap the stylesheet for the page. I would set the day stylesheet as the default and swap it out when necessary.

My initial thought is that you would want to perform this operation as soon as possible on the client to avoid any [potential browser reflow](http://www.sistrix.com/info/video/minimizing-browser-reflow).

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you’ll need to know the location of the client, the local sunrise and sunset time and the day of the year. Only locations at the equator have an almost constant 12 hour of day light all the year around.

This other answer on StackOverflow provides a good answer:

[Calculating sunrise/sunset times in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949074/calculating-sunrise-sunset-times-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Fun question. I wanted to give it a try and come up with something totally different than what was proposed so far. This is what I got:

```js
function isDay() {
    return (Date.now() + 60000 * new Date().getTimezoneOffset() + 21600000) % 86400000 / 3600000 > 12;
}
```

It will return true if it's between 6 AM and 6 PM, or false otherwise.

Breaking down into parts:

- `Date.now()` returns UTC epoch in milliseconds;
- `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` gets local time zone, in minutes, and `60000` just converts it to milliseconds;
- 21600000 represents 6 hours in milliseconds. This is a hack to pretend each day starts at 6 AM (will be explained in the end);
- 86400000 is how many milliseconds there is in a day, so `X % 86400000` will return how many milliseconds have passed since the current day begun; since we added 6 hours in the previous step, this is actually counting millis since 6 AM;
- we divide that result by 3600000 (number of milliseconds in an hour) to find out how many hours have passed since the day begun;
- since we added 6 hours to our clock, 6 AM is now 12 PM, and 6 PM is actually midnight. This is why the function checks to see if the value is greater than 12; if it is, it must be between 6 AM and 6 PM right now. Anything earlier than 6 AM or later than 6 PM becomes less than 12, according to that formula.

Of course, the same can be accomplished with:

```js
function isDay() {
  const hours = (new Date()).getHours();
  return (hours >= 6 && hours < 18);
}
```

But that is not even half as fun :-D

Comment: This is one of the reasons why software is hard to maintain. For fun aka over-engineering.

Comment: This is just an exercise, please don't take it seriously. I'd say it's obfuscated, not over-engineered. I sincerely hope you don't work for a company that runs code like this in production :-)